# Java3D: Rotating the universe by increments

Tags: java, rotation, java-3d

I'm trying to develop a Java3D method for rotating the universe in increments from the current viewing direction to the direction at the center of an object.

In other words, I want the 3D universe to rotate in, say, 100 short steps, so that an object that I click on appears to move gradually to the center of the screen.

I've reviewed the various answers to 3D rotation questions here on StackOverflow (as well as on the Web), but pretty much all of them are specific to rotating objects, not the world itself.

I've also tried to review my linear algebra, but that's not helping me to identify Java-specific functions that accomplish my requirements.

So far I've tried defining a set of incremental XYZ coordinates and dynamically using lookAt() in each pass through the loop. That almost works, but I don't see any way to preserve or obtain viewpoint values from one complete rotation pass to the next; each rotation pass starts out looking at the origin.

I've also tried defining a rotation matrix by obtaining the difference between the target and start transforms and dividing by the number of increments (and removing the scaling value), then adding that incremental rotation matrix to the current view direction at each pass through the loop. That works just fine for an increment value of 1. But splitting the rotation into two or more increments always generates the "BadTransformException: Non-congruent transform above ViewPlatform" error. (I've read the meager documentation of this exception in the Java3D API reference; it might as well have been written in Urdu for all I could make out from it. There seems to be no plain-English definition of 3D-context terms like "affine" or "shear" or "congruent" or "uniform" anywhere that Google can see.)

I then tried to cudgel my code into providing an AxisAngle4d, obtaining the angle (in radians), dividing that angle into my desired increments, and rotating by the incremental angle value. That rotated the world, all right, but nowhere near the object I picked, and not to any pattern I could see.

In desperation I tried using rotX and rotY (setting Z to the endpoint) on the extracted angle, and even blindly threw a couple of Math.cos() and Math.sin() wrappers in there. Still no joy.

My instincts are telling me that I've got the basics in place and that there's a relatively simple solution in Java3D. But clearly there's a comprehension wall I'm hitting. Rather than continue that, I thought I'd go ahead and see if anyone here can suggest a solution in Java3D. Code is preferred, but I'm willing to try to follow an explanation in linear algebra if that will get me to a code solution.

Below is the core of the method I'm using to schedule rotation increments using Java's Timer method. The part I need help with is just before the ActionListener. Presumably that's where the magic code would go that creates some kind of incremental rotation value I can apply (in the loop) to the current view direction in order to rotate the universe without getting "non-congruent" errors.

```
  private void flyRotate(double endX, double endY, double endZ)
  {
    // Rotate universe by increments until target object is centered in view
    // 
    // REQUIREMENTS
    // 1. Rotate the universe by NUMROTS increments from an arbitrary (non-origin)
    //   3D position and starting viewpoint to an ending viewpoint using the
    //   shortest path and preserving the currently defined "up" vector.
    // 2. Use the Java Timer() method to schedule the visual update for each
    //   incremental rotation.
    //
    // GLOBALS
    // rotLoop contains the integer loop counter for rotations (init'd to 0)
    // viewTransform3D contains rotation/translation for current viewpoint
    // t3d is a reusable Transform3D variable
    // vtg contains the view platform transform group
    // NUMROTS contains the number of incremental rotations to perform
    //
    // INPUTS
    // endX, endY, endZ contain the 3D position of the target object
    //
    // NOTE: Java3D v1.5.1 or later is required for the Vector3D getX(),
    //   getY(), and getZ() methods to work.

    final int delay = 20; // milliseconds between firings
    final int pause = 10; // milliseconds before starting

    // Get translation components of starting viewpoint vector
    Vector3d viewVector = new Vector3d();
    viewTransform3D.get(viewVector);
    final double startX = viewVector.getX();
    final double startY = viewVector.getY();
    final double startZ = viewVector.getZ();

    // Don't try to rotate to the location of the current viewpoint
    if (startX != endX || startY != endY || startZ != endZ)
    {
      // Get a copy of the starting view transform
      t3d = new Transform3D(viewTransform3D);

      // Define the initial eye/camera position and the "up" vector
      // Note: "up = +Y" is just the initial naive implementation
      Point3d  eyePoint = new Point3d(startX,startY,startZ);
      Vector3d upVector = new Vector3d(0.0,1.0,0.0);

      // Get target view transform
      // (Presumably something like this is necessary to get a transform
      // containing the ending rotation values.)
      Transform3D tNew = new Transform3D();
      Point3d viewPointTarg = new Point3d(endX,endY,endZ);
      tNew.lookAt(eyePoint,viewPointTarg,upVector);
      tNew.invert();

      // Get a copy of the target view transform usable by the Listener
      final Transform3D tRot = new Transform3D(tNew);

      //
      // (obtain either incremental rotation angle
      // or congruent rotation transform here)
      //

      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener()
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
        {
          if (++rotLoop <= NUMROTS)
          {
            // Apply incremental angle or rotation transform to the
            // current view
            t3d = magic(tRot);

            // Communicate the rotation to the view platform transform group
            vtg.setTransform(t3d);
          }
          else
          {
            timerRot.stop();
            rotLoop = 0;
            viewTransform3D = t3d;
          }
        }
      };

      // Set timer for rotation steps
      timerRot = new javax.swing.Timer(delay,taskPerformer);
      timerRot.setInitialDelay(pause);
      timerRot.start();
    }
  }
```

As is often the case with these things, there may be a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here by stepping back and rethinking the problem. I'm open to constructive suggestions there as well.

Thanks very much for any assistance with this!

---

UPDATE

Let me try to define the goal a little more concretely.

I have a Java3D universe containing many Sphere objects. I can click on each object and dynamically obtain its predefined XYZ coordinates.

At any moment, I am looking at all currently visible objects with a "camera" at a particular XYZ position and a view direction, which are contained in a transform holding the rotation matrix and translation vector.

(Note: I can both rotate the universe and translate through it using the mouse independently of clicking on objects. So there will be times when the view transform containing the camera's current rotation matrix and translation vector is not pointing at any target object with known XYZ coordinates.)

Given the camera transform and the object's XYZ coordinates, I want to rotate the universe around my current camera position until the selected object is centered in the screen. And I want to do this as a sequence of discrete incremental rotations, each of which is rendered so that the visible universe appears to "spin" in the viewing window until the selected object is centered. (I'm following this up with a translation to the object; that part at least is working!)

Example: Suppose the camera is at the origin, "up" is 1.0 along the Y-axis, and the selected object is centered ten units directly to my left. Assuming I had a 180-degree field of view, I could click on the half of the sphere that is visible all the way to the left of the screen and halfway between the top and bottom of the screen.

When I give the word, every visible object in the universe should appear to move in a sequence of evenly-spaced steps (let's say 50) from my left to my right until the selected object is exactly centered in the screen.

In coding terms, I need to work out the Java3D code by which I can rotate the universe around an imaginary line that runs through my camera position (currently at 0,0,0) and that is perfectly aligned with the Y-axis of the universe's coordinate system. (I.e., the axis of rotation sweeps through a plane where Z is always equal to the Z component of the camera's position.)

The complicating requirements are:

1. The camera can be translated somewhere in 3D space other than the origin.
2. Objects can be anywhere in 3D space with respect to the camera's current position and view, including being visible but off the screen (outside the view frustum) entirely.
3. Rotations should take the shortest path -- no spinning the universe more than 180 degrees at a time.
4. There should not be any "jump" or "twisting" of the visible universe as the first step in the rotation process; i.e., the current "up" vector (not the universe's absolute "up" vector) should be preserved.

So there's the question: given a transform holding the (virtual) camera's current translation and rotation information, and the XYZ coordinates in universe space of a target object, what Java3D code will rotate the universe around the camera in N equal steps until the object is centered in the screen?

Presumably this solution is in two parts: first, some 3D math (expressed in Java3D) to calculate the incremental rotation information given only the camera transform and object's XYZ coordinates; second, a loop that [applies the incremental rotation to the current viewing transform and updates the screen] until the loop counter equals the number of increments.

It's that 3D math part that's beating me. I'm not seeing and can't bash out a way to obtain some form of incremental rotation information from the current camera transform and target object position that I can then apply to the camera transform. At least, I haven't found any way that doesn't cause jumping or twisting or unequal incremental movement steps (or a "non-congruent transform above ViewPlatform" exception).

There must be a simple solution....

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why not just rotate and move the "camera/eye/viewport" in your world? This should give the same effect.

Comment: I agree; the tricky part is doing the rotation broken up into a series of incremental rotations -- that's what needs a solution.

Comment: Note: a perfect solution will also preserve the current "up" vector (no twisting the universe before/while performing the incremental rotation steps), and will work for starting points other than the origin. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, your goal is to rotate the camera so it centers on the selected object, but that rotation should not be about an arbitrary vector, but instead should preserve the camera's "up" direction.

A solution that might work then:

1. First, calculate the rotation angle (let's call it A) about the "up" vector necessary so that the camera is facing the object you want.
2. Second, calculate the translation distance/direction (let's call it D) necessary along the "up" vector so that the object lines up as necessary with the camera. This will likely just be the difference in the Z/Y coordinate between the camera/object.
3. Find dA and dD by diving A/D by N, the number of increments you want to take to smooth the motion.
4. In a timer/time loop increment A/D by dA/dD respectively N times, taking them to the final values. Remember that you are rotating the camera about it's "up" vector and current location, not about the origin..

If you want an even smoother, more realistic looking rotation, consider using [SLERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).